# Binding ListView to an ObservableCollection and two visual controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I want to bind a ListView to an ObservableCollection of strings which I want to modify with data from two visual controls (say, a prefix and a postfix for those strings).

A simplified example:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Name="tbPrefix"/>
<TextBox Name="tbPostfix"/>

<ListView Name="lvTarget"/>
```

C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> sources = GetFromSomewhere();

public IEnumerable<string> Items()
{
    foreach (var source in sources) 
    {
        yield return tbPrefix.Text + source + tbPostfix.Text;
    }
}
```

To keep the ListView updated I'm currently simply resetting its ItemsSource on the CollectionChanged event:

```
void sources_CollectionChanged(...)
{
    lvTarget.ItemsSource = Items();
}
```

But I also want the ListView to be bound to changes in *any* of its three sources: the collection and the prefix/postfix controls. I think I want either a MultiBinding or a MultiDataTrigger but I can't quite wrap my head around the syntax and all examples I could find bind a control to other *controls*, while I also have that ObservableCollection as a source.

P.S. Sorry if it's simple and obvious, it's only my third day with WPF and I'm a little overwhelmed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable collection is used to notify when the items in the collection are changed such as add, remove, move, etc... and it will not notify if you change the text in the string. First best practice rule in WPF to use ViewModel to bind properties not code behind. You can solve this problem by with the following:

1- Create a new class called SomethingViewModel

2- Add to it all the properties needs binding to your view:

```
public class SomethingViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _prefix;
    private string _postfix;

    public SomethingViewModel()
    {
        Sources = new ObservableCollection<string>(/*pass initial data of the list*/);
        Sources.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged("Items");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> Sources { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Items
    {
        get { return Sources.Select(x => string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", Prefix, x, Postfix)).ToList(); }
    }

    public string Prefix
    {
        get
        {
            return _prefix;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_prefix == value) return;
            _prefix = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Prefix");
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }

    public string Postfix
    {
        get
        {
            return _postfix;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_postfix == value) return;
            _postfix = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Postfix");
            OnPropertyChanged("Items"); // we will notify that the items list has changed so the view refresh its items
        }
    }
}
```

3- In the constructor of the View put the following code to init the datacontext of the view:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.DataContext= new SomethingViewModel();
}
```

4-Finally bind the view elements to the viewmodel properties:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Prefix,Mode=TwoWay}/>
<TextBox  Text={Binding Postfix,Mode=TwoWay}/>

<ListView ItemsSource={Binding Items}/>
```

5-If you want to change the items in the source don't initialize a new object just use the method:

```
Sources.Clear();
Sources.Add();
```

Comment: I ended up implementing the ViewModel the way you showed. The only thing that bugs me is a lot of almost identical boilerplate code around defining properties like Prefix and Postfix that fire OnPropertyChanged (I actually have 3 of them). I guess I could make a generic class for them?

Comment: @isagalaev The OnPropertyChanged is required to reflect the modifications in your viewmodel to the view... But you can do a base class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged and then make all your viewmodels inherits from it. This way you can reduce the need to write the code related to property changed in the class (the event and the method).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Please note that using a DataTemplate, as in Clemens' answer, would be the better solution if you only need to modify the visual appearance of the items. If you want to actually have combined strings as items, go the ViewModel way. The following solution is not best practice and tries to demonstrate how MultiBindings work.

---

This problem would better be solved in your ViewModel. Converters (and MultiConverters in particular) should only be used when absolutely necessary.

But as this is your 3rd day with WPF, you shouldn't be bothered with MVVM yet.

1. Make your Window class the DataContext of itself:

   ```
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;
   }
   ```

   This will let us use data binding from the Window to properties defined on it.
2. We could use a default property for our items, but then WPF won't notice when the property value changes. We will use a [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) for now:

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty
       = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof (IEnumerable<string>), typeof (MainWindow));

   public IEnumerable<string> Items
   {
       get { return (IEnumerable<string>) GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
       set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
   }

   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       this.DataContext = this;

       this.Items = new[] {"sdf", "fdsa", "tgrg"};
   }
   ```

   Whenever we call the setter of this property, WPF will notice it and update all bindings to this property. We also updated our constructor to load some values initially.

   We could also have implemented [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) - in fact, ViewModels use this pattern - and/or used an ObservableCollection. Unfortunately, an ObservableCollection change won't retrigger a MultiBinding, so we just use `IEnumerable<string>` as type.
3. Let's add the bindings in XAML now:

   ```
   <StackPanel>
       <TextBox Name="prefixTextBox" />
       <TextBox Name="postfixTextBox" />
       <ListBox>
           <ListBox.ItemsSource>
               <MultiBinding>
                   <MultiBinding.Converter>
                       <wpfApplication1:PrefixPostfixConverter />
                   </MultiBinding.Converter>
                   <Binding Path="Items" />
                   <Binding ElementName="prefixTextBox" Path="Text" />
                   <Binding ElementName="postfixTextBox" Path="Text" />
               </MultiBinding>
           </ListBox.ItemsSource>
       </ListBox>
   </StackPanel>
   ```

   Okay, we set the ItemsSource using a MultiBinding. That's essentially doing what you did before in your change handler: Whenever one of its child bindings changes, it calls the specified converter and updates ItemsSource with its result. But what is this `PrefixPostfixConverter`?
4. Add the PrefixPostfixConverter class:

   ```
   public class PrefixPostfixConverter : IMultiValueConverter 
   {
       public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           if (values == null || values.Length != 3)
               throw new ArgumentException("values");

           var items = values[0] as IEnumerable;
           var prefix = values[1] as string;
           var postfix = values[2] as string;

           if (items == null || prefix == null || postfix == null)
               return null;

           return items.Cast<object>()
                       .Select(i => prefix + i + postfix)
                       .ToArray();
       }

       public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
       {
           throw new NotSupportedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   This takes the input from your three bindings (coming in as `values` parameter) and creates the combined values as array.

Comment: Thanks! Am I right thinking of DependencyProperty as a sort of a quick-and-dirty way to emulate firing PropertyChanged events for a single property, as I would do in a custom ViewModel code?

Comment: MainWindow is a "view". As such, it has DependencyObject in its base class hierarchy and can use dependency properties. There is no need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. ViewModels though are usually not derived from DependencyObject. ViewModels try to ignore "view" code. Many ViewModels can exist without knowledge of any of the System.Windows namespaces, which makes them easily testable. They implement INotifyPropertyChange to notify changes to the binding system.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code behind. Just create an appropriate DataTemplate for the ListView items:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbPrefix}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=tbPostfix}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note also the `Items` is a public property here, not a method, and that you should declare it in a view model class. An instance of this view model class would be assigned to the `DataContext` of your view (e.g. MainWindow).

Comment: Looks like I mislead you with my over-simplified example, sorry. The actual task is not simply concatenate strings, it takes a list of picture file names, reads their picture taken time and constructs a new file name based on a string template and a counter. So I really so need some actual computation behind the scenes.

Comment: That should all be done in your view model. Instead of string items, you would have an item data class with a property that returns the constructed file name.