# Failing to successfully expose my ViewModel data to my View for XAML binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I'm building a Windows Universal app and trying to expose data from my ViewModel to my View so that I can bind it to XAML elements. I have completely commented out all of my code at this point and am just writing lines of test code to try and get it to work, that is what is in the examples below. Binding directly from the View (if I create an object there as a test) does work.

Please help me to understand where I am going wrong, I think I've read every binding tutorial on the internet and still just don't get it.

View (**MainPage.xaml.cs**):

```
public MainPage()
{   
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();

}
```

ViewModel (**MainViewModel.cs**):

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public Term newTerm = new Term
    {
        TermName = "Table",
        TermDescription = "You eat dinner on it"    
    };
}
```

XAML (**MainPage.xaml**):

```
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding newTerm}" x:Name="mvvmStack" Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock x:Name="mvvmTermName" Text="{Binding TermName,  FallbackValue='Fallingback'}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="mvvmDescription" Text="{Binding TermDescription, FallbackValue='Fallingback', TargetNullValue='Unknown'}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'newTerm' property not found on ''. BindingExpression: Path='newTerm' DataItem=''; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel' (Name='mvvmStack'); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')
```

I have read about this type of error and although I have some idea of what it is trying to say I cannot work out how to fix it. I'm very much a complete beginner with coding, especially C# so please take that into account when answering :-)

Comment: The member `newTerm` isn't a property (which the exception message asks for) but just a public field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to change it from field to a property and it will be working correctly. You can't bind to fields.
EDIT:

```
private Term _term;
public Term NewTerm{
    get{return _term;}
    set
    {
       _term= value;
       OnPropertyChanged("Term");
    }
}
```

if you need to add notify the view of changes in the viewmodel you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
check this answer it will provide an example for property changed. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27685925/1448382

If you want to bind the view to sub properties, you have two options depending on the situation:

1- Relative Binding: this scenario is used when you will not modify the properties inside the Term object from the ViewModel i.e. they will be just initialized in the viewmodel and can be modified in the view, just like the way you are doing it. Plesae note, that anything you need to bind to should be a property and not a field.

2- Binding to Viewmodel directly: this scenario is used when you will modify the properties inside the Term object from the Viewmodel after the view load. This way you will need to add properties to the viewmodel for the properties TermName and TermDescription.

```
public string TermName{
    get{return NewTerm.Name;}
    set{NewTerm.Name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TermName");
    }//The same is applied for TermDescription
```

But be aware that you will need to remove the binding on the Stackpanel object since you have defined the properties directly in the Viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but then I still get this error for the controls where I am trying to bind a property:

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'TermName' property not found on ''. BindingExpression: Path='TermName' DataItem=''; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.StackPanel' (Name='mvvmStack'); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Comment: OK, let me look at that - does that mean I cannot expose any data to my view WITHOUT using INotifyProperyChanged? I thought that was used only if your data changes after the app has loaded.

Comment: where is the term name defined?

Comment: @James you can't notify the view without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged think of this as telling the view that "we have changed the value in the viewmodel you need to update yourself".

Comment: Ok, I thought that when I create a new instance of the view with 'DataContext = new MainViewModel()' that the view is notified of the data i.e. the Term object and that only if something changed I needed INotifyProperyChanged. Let me try implementing it now.

Comment: @James: you can use binding without any change notification at all. But as Manar says, the binding won't be able to respond to changes to the property value; i.e. the value will be assigned to the bound UI element when it's initially bound, and changes in the UI will be able to change the property value, but the UI won't be updated if the property is changed by some other mechanism. Note that you don't have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged per se, but you do have to implement _some_ WPF-binding-compatible mechanism (`DependencyObject` is the other typical approach).

Comment: @James You don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in all your viewmodels classes. You can write a base class such as ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and make your Viewmodels classes inherits from it.

Comment: @ManarHusrieh / Peter Thank you -  I'm looking through your answers and your examples now. This is all quite new to me, thank you for your time though.

Comment: @ManarHusrieh Thank you, I've managed to get an example working by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. I also used this source as a helpful example: http://jesseliberty.com/2012/06/28/c-5making-inotifypropertychanged-easier/. I'll now try and apply the concept to my original app code.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <viewModels:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
</Page.Resources>
```

And then:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="mvvmStack" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="mvvmTermName" Text="{Binding newTerm.TermName, Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}  FallbackValue='Fallingback'}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="mvvmDescription" Text="{Binding newTerm.TermDescription, Source={StaticResource MainViewModel} FallbackValue='Fallingback', TargetNullValue='Unknown'}" /></StackPanel>
```

Of cource `newTerm` should be an property with INotifyChanged